# Continuity equation for the density of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, density-function, optimal-transport, transport-equation

From the paper of [Ambrosio-Crippa](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-royal-society-of-edinburgh-section-a-mathematics/article/abs/continuity-equations-and-ode-flows-with-nonsmooth-velocity/DD2A02C300757F63F7F0A96FAD8A70C5), it is known that if $\beta:\mathbb R^d\times[0, T[\longrightarrow\mathbb R^d$ is suitably regular, then the system
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial t}(x, t)+\operatorname{div}(\beta(x, t)\mu(x, t))=0,&(x, t)\in\mathbb R^d\times]0, T]\\
\mu(\cdot, 0)=\mu_0
\end{cases}
$$
is well-posed. In the case when $\mu_0$ is absolutely continuous, that is $\mu_0=m_0\mathcal L^d$, where $m_0:\mathbb R^d\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is the density, all the measures $\mu(\cdot, t)$ are absolutely continuous too, and their density $m(\cdot, t)$ can be explicitly computed as
$$
m(\cdot, t)=\frac{m_0(\cdot)}{\operatorname{det}J\Phi_t(\cdot)}\ \circ\ \Phi_t^{-1}(\cdot),\qquad(\triangle)
$$
where $\Phi_t$ is the flow associated to
$$
\begin{cases}
y'(s)=\beta(y(s), s),&s\in]0, T[\\
y(0)=x
\end{cases}.
$$

**Question.** Is it true that $m$ satisfies (in the sense of distributions) the continuity equation
$$
(\star)\ \ \begin{cases}
\frac{\partial m}{\partial t}(x, t)+\operatorname{div}(\beta(x, t)m(x, t))=0,&(x, t)\in\mathbb R^d\times]0, T]\\
m(\cdot, 0)=m_0
\end{cases}?
$$
I proved that, with suitable regularity hypotheses on the field $\beta$, if $m_0\in H^1(\mathbb R^d)\cap W^{1, \infty}(\mathbb R^d)$ then $m(\cdot, t)$ belongs to the same space for every $t$. I think that $(\star)$ is true but, to be honest, i cannot prove that using directly $(\triangle)$. Can you help me or give me some suggestion?

Comment: Shouldn't that be a trivial consequence of your first PDE? I don't see the necessity to use $\Delta$.

Comment: Yes, it should be and really it is. But what regularity w.r.t. time should the density $m$ have? Can I infer it by the properties of $\mu$? Thank you

Comment: I would expect the same regularity as for $\mu$.